# UCEProtect Level 3 - Emails land in SPAM

Tags: email, spam, lamp, ubuntu-12.04

I am not sure how i can have remove the IP from UCEPROTECT Level 3.
Or a way in which i can send emails without them landing into spam.

The IP which i have used has only sent emails to the users which they have asked for and naturally not listed for spamming. But the Service provider is.

Any suggestion?, as i don't see the institution for which the setup has been made would change the ISP at this stage.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the UCEPROTECT website:

> UCEPROTECT-Level 3 lists all IP's within an ASN except those approved and clean IP's that are registered at ips.whitelisted.org if more than 100 IP's, but also a minimum of 0.2% of all IP's allocated to this ASN got Level 1 listed within the last 7 days.

UCEPROTECT-Level 3 lists only 320 ASNs, so your ISP is probably really one of the worst spammers. If you don't want to change your ISP, you should get your IP addres registered at ips.whitelisted.org.

Comment: Yes, I could notice that it is one of the worst ISP's here. But being the only option i have for using it at this moment, i would have to use the ISP for now. The issue is the IP has never been used for spamming. No direct way to remove it from UCEPROTECT? One way i noticed is to complain the ISP to make sure spamming is being watched and stopped from their end and it would automatically remove from UCEPROTECT-Level 3... (but it seems that many have already tried and failed with the ISP).

Comment: Ok, you still have the option of getting listed at ips.whitelisted.org. That won't be free, though.

Comment: Monthly, Yearly cost... I noticed that option alone :(. Paid removal option :). RBL at its best :D.

Comment: Well, what did you expect? There is no magic switch that can solve your problem.

Comment: *RBL at its best :D.* - well yes. Lie own with dogs, you get fleas. The RBLs are trying to increase the cost of being a spammer or being an ISP that supports spammers and the RBLs do this both by blocking spam havens and by brining pressure on 'legitimate' users of that ISP.

Comment: I think i would try to convince my client to have his ISP changed soon or surely he can go with the payment options :) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP must take steps to control outbound spam from its network, to reduce UCEPROTECT listings below the level 3 threshold. I suggest contacting your ISP and working on escalating your support request to the highest possible level. Many ISPs are starting to take this issue seriously - they need to hear from their customers the pain this is causing them.

Comment: Yes, i have already contacted the ISP with the issue, waiting for their response.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Uce-Protect. Uce-Protect RBL is a extortion racket. Read about this guy here: https://uceprotect.wtf/ for more info.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).